# Showing legend/classified features in OpenLayers from qgis2web?

Tags: openlayers, qgis2web, layer-switcher

[image][image][image]

How can I show legend / classified features in my layer switcher legend in OpenLayers from qgis2web similar to how the Leaflet option exports it?
Openlayers shows legend items fine as a single style but if the layer has subclasses only the main layer name shows in the layer switcher legend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm that it is the symbology with rules that is not exported correctly.
It is only a legend problem because the themes can be seen correctly on the map.
You can solve by manually editing the "title" in the layer you are interested in in the layer.js file

Esempio:

```
title: 'Pai Esondazioni agg 2016<br />\
    <img src="styles/legend/PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11_0.png" /> R1<br />\
    <img src="styles/legend/PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11_1.png" /> R2<br />\
    <img src="styles/legend/PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11_2.png" /> R3<br />\
    <img src="styles/legend/PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11_3.png" /> R4<br />'
```

Unfortunately you will have to create the png icons by hand and then recall them

Answer (score 0):

In my legend, OpenLayers are visible:

[image: legend]

Set up like this in QGIS:

[image: qgis]

Comment: Well thanks but not quite!  That is how my layers are set up in QGIS, the only difference is I have used "Rule Based" criteria instead of "Categorized".  Is it the "Rule Based" that OpenLayers doesn't like?  (See new image above.)